# MySQL swap numbers for letters in field

Tags: mysql, replace

If I take a value of 12345 from MySQL and I want to display that at the front end as Mo Tu We Th Fr, how can I do that allowing for all possible combinations?

I could write a case statement but there are going to be many hundreds of combinations to cover all possible values.

The value will be anything from 1 to 7 characters long using between digits between 1 and 7 and could be in any order so 3417 should read We Th Mo Su whilst 645 should read Sa Th Fr and so on. I cannot do this in the application so have to try and figure out how to do it in MySQL. These are stored in MySQL as a varchar in a single column.

Can I use replace multiple times in the same select so something like:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(field, '1', 'Mo '), '2', 'Tu'), '3', 'We')
```

or is there another way?

Comment: Why not use a correlating table ?

Comment: @Pogrindis I'm guessing these aren't integers stored singly in a column, but rather strings of integers in a [var]char column, and he wants to swap out the numbers in the string (weekdays?) for correlated strings (abbreviated day names?).

Comment: @bhttoan, this needs more detail. Please clarify whether the situation is single values to strings (simple join) or multiple numbers in a string being replaced with correlated strings. Right now, everyone's piling on trying to tell you how to do a join.

Comment: @MarcL. if I follow, the string of integers would need to be split then, joined to the select statement and returned to caller for concatination ?

Comment: It's (probably) ways easier to do that in your application language.

Comment: If it really is just day-of-week number(s) to strings, for mono-cultural purposes, a la `1356` to `Mo We Fr Sa` then any kind of split/join/concat solution is overkill. I'd just go with the multi-`REPLACE` solution. For the moment, still needs more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper table that contains 2 columns :
1, su
2, mo
3, ...

then just join the day number to get the second column of the helper table.

If all you want to do is display this in a fronend, you can have a "dictionary" to translate the values.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say for example you have a Table in the structure

```
tl_days
__________
id | alias
```

And we have some data such as

```
id: 1, alias : Mon
id: 2, alias : Tue
```

We can run a simple query to check the id against an array of numbers.

```
SELECT alias FROM 'tl_days' WHERE id in (1,2,3,4);
```

Will return the days as your abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write replace for all the values if there are multiple of them, Instead create a mapping table 1|su,2|mo ..., Then use join to  fetch the 'su','mo' values   from the mapping table

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to ensure that the table schema data matches. If changing from numeric value to text value is acceptable.

```
Update table_name set column_name = 
  ( 
     CASE 
       when column_name = 1 then 'Mo'
       when column_name =  2 then 'Tu'
       when column_name =  3 then 'We'
       when column_name =  4 then 'Th'
       when column_name =  5 then 'Fr'
   End 
   );
```

Here is an [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f24a45/1) displaying such a change.